# Cannot break debugger for kernel driver windows 10

Tags: windows, visual-studio, kernel, driver

going through [Hello world tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439665(v=vs.85).aspx) for writing kernel windows driver 10, I had a trouble in step 9 in second section:

```
On the Debug menu, choose "Break All". The debugger on the host computer will break into the target computer. In the Debugger Immediate window, you can see the kernel debugging command prompt: kd>.`
```

The problem is that when I do Break All the debugger does not stop and I cannot access the debugger command line. In step 8 i run "Debugging tools for Windows - Kernel Debugger" from VS 2015, because I don't have simple debug option.

**My environment setup:**

- Visual Studio 2015
- WDK 10
- VirtualBox (with Windows 10 x64)

Windows 10 on target machine is provisioned propely, I can connect it and everything seems to work fine.

I've also found that in this [Troubleshoting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/develop/troubleshooting-configuration-of-driver-deployment--testing-and-debugging) is a section which describes what should I do in such case (kernel debug), but I do not actually know how to, do things according these steps.

```
1.Deploy the driver with breakpoints disabled.
```

I tried adding any breakpoints before running debugger.

```
2.Manually break into the kernel-mode debugger.
```

And this point does not work as I think i have to use "Build all" command.

I do not actually see if I've done something wrong. So any suggestion what could be wrong and how to break to the kernel debbuging will be appreciated.

Comment: are you load virtual os with debugger enabled ? `BCDEdit /debug` I mean - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542191(v=vs.85).aspx - you need create  boot entry with debugger enabled

Comment: I set it, restarted PC, but still does not work.

Comment: and you configure to redirect COM port to named pipe ? configure and attach debugger at boot ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439359(v=vs.85).aspx - use pipes

Comment: Great! I've created com1 to named pipe connection in virtual machine, set `bcdedit /dbgsettings serial com:1 baudrate:115200 ` and set it in visual studio in provisioning target device setting. And it finally works, Thank you very much :)